# passing data in vuejs using props

Tags: vue.js

I'm doing image upload in vuejs. And I separate the upload file, use props to listen

In `user.vue`

```
<template>
 <a-form
    :form="form"
    @submit.prevent="uploadFile"
  >
  <a-tabs v-model="activeKey" tabPosition="right">=
      <image-upload
        :option="{ 
           title: 'Upload',
           placeholder: 'File upload'
        }"
      />
  </a-tabs>
</a-form>
</template>
<script>
import { Tabs, Form } from "ant-design-vue";

Vue.use(Tabs);
Vue.use(Form);

export default {
  components: {
    image-upload: () =>
      import(
        /* webpackChunkName: "js/chunks/photo-platform.chunk" */ "./upload/index.vue"
      ),
  },
 methods: {
   uploadFile() {
      this.form.validateFields((err, values) => {
         console.log(values);
      });
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

In `upload/index.vue`

```
<template>
<b-row>
  <b-col md="3">
     <b-form-group>
        <label>{{option.title}}</label>
          <b-form-file
          accept="image/*"
          placeholder= {{ option.placeholder }}
          drop-placeholder="Drop file here..."
          name="titleImage"
          v-model="titleImage"
          @change="changeTitle"
          multiple
          />
       </b-form-group>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
</template>
<script>
  import {
  BCard,
  BRow,
  BCol,
  BForm,
} from "bootstrap-vue";
export default {
  props: {
     option: Object
  },
  components: {
    BFormGroup,
    BRow,
    BCol,
    BCard,
  },
  data() {
    return {
       titleImage: [],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeTitle() {
      ////
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I am using `props` in vuejs. Now I want when I select multiple images in `upload/index.vue`, and press submit form `uploadFile` in `user.vue`, I will get the data of the image I just selected in. Please give me your opinion. I'm new to vuejs so it's really hard for me. Thanks

Comment: You can use "emit event" for passing data from child to parent.

Comment: @Bulent What if i want to pass an array?

Comment: @deskeay Yes, you can pass an array. You can pass any data you want, just emit from child to parent component and listen via an event. 
https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#v-model-arguments